# PrimeNg Calendar component - how to set property globally?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a calendar (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar) and I would like to set some properties globally - for every time I use element "p-calendar". (e.g. "firstDayOfWeek"=1, dataType="string", dateFormat="yy-mm-dd").

Is it possible to change these properties when importing CalendarModule or in some different way?

Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/calendar/calendar.ts) and the component's constructor, you'll see that it doesn't inject anything "global" that would allow that. So you're left with good old copy-paste.

One thing you can do to make it a little less heart breaking would be to provide some config on the module level and inject it as a public property into places that use the PrimeNG calendar - this way if your customer decides something needs changing you'll only have to change it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use a directive

```
import { Directive, OnInit, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControlName } from '@angular/forms';
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/calendar';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myCalendar]'
})
export class CalendarDirective implements OnInit {
    dateFormat = 'yy/mm/dd';

    monthFormat = 'yy/mm';

    yearFormat = 'yy';

    constructor(private primeCalendar: Calendar, @Optional() private fc: FormControlName) {
        this.primeCalendar.dateFormat = this.getDateFormat();
        this.primeCalendar.selectOtherMonths = true;
        this.primeCalendar.showIcon = true;
        this.primeCalendar.dataType = 'string';
        this.primeCalendar.hourFormat = '24';
        this.primeCalendar.appendTo = 'body';
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this.primeCalendar.timeOnly) {
            this.primeCalendar.icon = 'pi pi-clock';

            //auto fill current time
            this.primeCalendar.onShow.subscribe(() => {
                if (this.primeCalendar.inputFieldValue === '') {
                    const current = new Date();
                    this.primeCalendar.value = current;
                    this.fc.control.setValue(current.getHours() + ':' + current.getMinutes());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    getDateFormat(): string {
        if (this.primeCalendar.view === 'month') {
            return `${this.monthFormat}`;
        } else if (this.primeCalendar.view === 'year') {
            return `${this.yearFormat}`;
        } else {
            return this.dateFormat;
        }
    }
}
```

how to use it...

```html
 <p-calendar formControlName="abc_date" myCalendar></p-calendar>
```